# How can I link custom wordpress taxonomy terms to terms in other custom taxonomies?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a site where it has woodworking tools I have a few custom taxonomies
Tool Brand,
Tool Type,
Model Numbers

I am looking for a way to link the model numbers to the Tool Brand and Tool Type taxonomies without having to make model numbers a redundant hierarchy

```
Tool Brand
 - Dewalt
 - Makita
 - Milwaukee
Tool Type
 - Sander
 - Miter Saw
Model Number
 - DCW200
 - DCW6411
```

That is how it's currently setup, but I would like to it where the model number DCW6411 is known to be a Tool Type Sander and the Brand Dewalt

One way I could do this is make Model number a hierarchy have the brand names as top then under the tool type where it repeat then model number but I would like to avoid this since it seems redundant. Is there a way around this or is this the only way?

```
Model Number
 - Dewalt
   - Sander
     - DCW200 
     - DCW6411
   - Miter Saw
 - Makita
   - Sander
   - Miter Saw
```

Going the secondary route I would have to give ever model number term it's own parent within the model number tax a parent Tool Type and a Parent brand and I feel like there has to be a way to just link them to the other taxonomies since I already have the tool type and tool brands.